# How to get sync status on headless dropbox install

Tags: dropbox

I have Dropbox running on a Debian server. I'd like to be able to find out the sync status - like you get when you right-click the dropbox icon in Windows, e.g. "Downloading 123 files" or "All up-to-date".

I'm sure there's a way but Google is apparently not my friend on this one.

Pls. note that I'm talking about the headless server install of dropbox, not the more common dropbox + dropbox-nautilus set up used for a typical linux desktop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you need to download the [dropbox script](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py) for managing the daemon. Instructions on the [dropbox website](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx)

```
wget -O ~/dropbox.py https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py
chmod a+x ~/dropbox.py
~/dropbox.py status
```

You can also create a symlink to your dropbox script, so you don't have to type `~/dropbox.py` to run it every time.

```
sudo ln -s ~/dropbox.py /usr/local/bin/dropbox
dropbox status
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed that tiny link in the small print at the bottom of Dropbox's page! In case anyone else reads this: nb. that the dropbox.py script must be run as the same user as the dropbox daemon is running as.

Answer (score 1):

With the helper script installed (part of the .deb package)

```
$ dropbox help
Dropbox command-line interface

commands:

Note: use dropbox help <command> to view usage for a specific command.

 status       get current status of the dropboxd
 help         provide help
 puburl       get public url of a file in your dropbox
 stop         stop dropboxd
 running      return whether dropbox is running
 update       download latest version of dropbox
 start        start dropboxd
 filestatus   get current sync status of one or more files
 ls           list directory contents with current sync status
 autostart    automatically start dropbox at login
 exclude      ignores/excludes a directory from syncing
 lansync      enables or disables LAN sync


$ dropbox status
```

Comment: yeah, that's the gui version and is not there for the headless install. There *is* a dropbox command (`~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox`) but this starts the daemon only; it doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: /usr/bin/dropbox should be installed as part of the .deb installation.  (and no, I didn't mark you down)

Comment: Didn't install from .deb, installed as [described on Dropbox.com](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx), but as other answer pointed out, I missed the management script which for some odd reason is not bundled with the daemon! Thank you for your time.